# Covariance Using Expected Value

Tags: statistics

In the book Probabilistic Robotics, I am seeing a statement saying that for a random variable X, because expected value is linear ($E[aX + b] = aE[X] + b$), we can make the following statement:

$$\text{Cov}[X] = \text{E}[X - \text{E}[X]]^2 = \text{E}[X^2] - \text{E}[X]^2$$

How do we simplify to the RHS?

Comment: linearity and $E[X]$ is a number

Comment: try expanding E[X-E[X]]

Comment: Expand $\text{E}[X - \text{E}[X]]^2$ and then note $E[X\, E[X]] = E[X]\, E[X] = E[X]^2$